# Compute running empirical rank in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table of the form

```
CREATE TABLE data (n INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, x REAL)
```

and I would like to compute, for each row, the empirical rank of `data.x` over all rows with a smaller `data.n`. Logically something like

```
SELECT data.n, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM data 
  JOIN data AS megadata
 WHERE data.n >= megadata.n
   AND data.x >= megadata.x
 GROUP BY data.n
```

but this seems very expensive, considering I can compute the ranks over all data via

```
SELECT data.n, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY data.x ASC) AS totalcnt
  FROM data
```

quite quickly.

Is there a way to use SQL (window functions) to achieve what I want more efficiently?

Currently I'm computing and maintaining this outside the database as the data streams in, using a heap-style datastructure [SortedList](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html), which feels exactly like what a window function *could* do for me, if I only knew SQL syntax better.

**Example**
The following script

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from sortedcontainers import SortedList

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
with conn:
    conn.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE data (n INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, x REAL)
    """)
    conn.executemany("""
        INSERT INTO DATA VALUES(?, ?)
    """, [ (1, 7), (2, 10), (3, 8), (4, 6), (5, 9), (6, 7) ])
    print("---------- Input Data -------------")
    print(pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM data", conn))
    # This solution feels O(n^2)
    print("-------- Desired Output -----------")
    print(pd.read_sql_query("""
        SELECT data.n, COUNT(*) AS cnt
          FROM data 
          JOIN data AS megadata 
         WHERE data.n >= megadata.n
           AND data.x >= megadata.x
         GROUP BY data.n
    """, conn))
    # Whereas this solution is definitely O(n log(n))
    print("--------- Sorted List ------------")
    sl = SortedList()
    for rownum, (n, x) in enumerate(conn.execute("""
        SELECT * 
          FROM DATA
         ORDER BY n
    """)):
        runningrank = 1 + sl.bisect_right(x)
        print(f'{rownum} {n} {runningrank}')
        sl.add(x)
```

produces the desired output

```
---------- Input Data -------------
   n     x
0  1   7.0
1  2  10.0
2  3   8.0
3  4   6.0
4  5   9.0
5  6   7.0
-------- Desired Output -----------
   n  cnt
0  1    1
1  2    2
2  3    2
3  4    1
4  5    4
5  6    3
--------- Sorted List ------------
0 1 1
1 2 2
2 3 2
3 4 1
4 5 4
5 6 3
```

but the SQL query is much slower than streaming the data in order into a [SortedList](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html) and calling [bisect_right](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html#sortedcontainers.SortedList.bisect_right).

Comment: Please add sample data in the form of an input table, and also include the output you want.

Comment: This is not an OUTER join even if you define it as a LEFT join. The WHERE clauses transform it to an INNER join.

Comment: @forpas: cool, yeah, I'll edit the post to get rid of the LEFT OUTER part.  nonetheless, the select-self-join is very slow.  however, i'm not *demanding* a window function solution, just an effective one.  so i'll edit the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to deal with this requirement by a single window function, without the need of subqueries.

Also, the conditions that you want to apply prevent the use of an index as it is documented in [The SQLite Query Optimizer Overview](https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html).

Your query is fine and theoretically (but [not actually](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#where_clause_filtering_)) it would be better to remove the `WHERE` clause and move its conditions to an `ON` clause:

```
SELECT d1.n, 
       COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM data d1 INNER JOIN data d2
ON d2.n <= d1.n AND d2.x <= d1.x
GROUP BY d1.n;
```

Also, I believe that by simply using a correlated subquery the performance would be at least equal (if not better):

```
SELECT d1.n, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data d2 WHERE d2.n <= d1.n AND d2.x <= d1.x) AS cnt
FROM data d1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/BcW7xboL).

Comment: I can confirm the correlated subquery is faster than the original join, although both are much slower than using the SortedList.  It's a shame, RANK-ing on one column while ORDER-ing on another seems like a natural thing but there's no built-in window function for it (?).